# Set woocommerce default page to orders instead of new dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Simply after the update of woocommerce 4.0 a new admin dashboard is added to the woocommerce menu items and become the main menu item when you click on woocommerce from the admin panel it redirects you to the new dashboard page instead of orders page as before, we still use the dashboard we don't need to disable it completely.

But we want the woocommerce menu item when its clicked to go to the orders page as before the 4.0 update not the new dashboard item.

Comment: You could use JS to change the href attribute of the "WooCommerce" menu item. Have you tried something like that?

Comment: And how is this can achieved ?, have a way ?